# Comparing 2 arrays for at least 3 similarities

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I want to compare 2 arrays with each other to count the similarities that they have.

```js
[ 401, 271, 259, 260, 342, 410 ]

[ 401, 12021, 923, 235, 342, 410 ]
```

The above arrays should output 3. Right now I have a forEach inside a forEach just going through each one individually to check the other array individually for the same number.

Comment: Can you show your forEach attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Array.reduce() method

```js
const a = [ 401, 271, 259, 260, 342, 410 ]

const b = [ 401, 12021, 923, 235, 342, 410 ]


console.log(a.reduce((acc,curr, i)=>{
    if(curr==b[i]) acc+=1
    return acc
},0));
```

Comment: This worked thank you!